# Blender crashes using a bmesh python operator

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, operator, bmesh

The following python operator crashes blender. I'm using 2.93.5 on Win10.

Strangely however, if I use the python terminal built into blender I can `import bpy, bmesh` and `from bmesh.types import BMVert` and then paste the entire code between  `### START ###` and `### END ###` and it all works fine, with no crash.

But when I try to run the code from the python terminal by typing `bpy.ops.mesh.generate_arms()` then blender will immediately crash.

Is there something wrong with the code, or is this something I should file a bug report for blender?

```
import bpy, bmesh
from bmesh.types import BMVert

class MESH_OT_Generate_Arms(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Generate Arms"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.generate_arms"
    bl_label = "Generate Arms"

    def execute(self, context):
        
        ### START ###

        #create cube
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=0.1)
        
        # turn on edit mode
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        
        # get the mesh data of the active object
        ao_d = context.active_object.data
        
        # get bmesh from ao_d
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(ao_d)

        bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
        
        # extrude
        ext = bmesh.ops.extrude_face_region(bm, geom=[bm.faces[1]])
        
        # translate
        bmesh.ops.translate(bm, vec=(0, 1, 0), verts=[v for v in ext["geom"] if isinstance(v, BMVert)])
        
        bm.normal_update()
        
        # update the viewport so we can see what we are doing
        bmesh.update_edit_mesh(ao_d, True, True)
        
        # return to object mode
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

        ### END ###
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
      
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MESH_OT_Generate_Arms)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MESH_OT_Generate_Arms)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

Here is a screenshot of just cutting and pasting the text in the terminal, showing that it works fine. It only crashes when I run it in the terminal with `bpy.ops.mesh.generate_arms()`

It still immediately crashes blender when I run `bpy.ops.mesh.generate_arms()` in the terminal.

It also immediately crashes blender if I search with F3, and then click "Generate Arms" to run it that way.

[image]

Comment: one problem is that you shouldn't call bm.free when you use bmesh_from_edit_mesh but should instead call bmesh.update_edit_mesh, which you've already done.  Also you don't need the del call, since bm will go out of scope anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I have now removed those, and updated the code above, it still crashes blender as I have described.

Comment: I think I have narrowed it down to line right after `# extrude` because I commented out the file line by line, testing each time if it would crash, starting from the bottom, and it continued to crash until I commented out that line. But I have no idea why that line might be cause it to crash.

Comment: You're using bpy.context where you should use context, although that shouldn't cause a crash.  The code works for me when I run it standalone, rather than as part of the execute method, if that's any help.

Comment: I updated the code using just context, still crashes. Are you using Win10 as well as Blender_2.93.5?

Comment: got it.  vec takes a tuple not a vector.  Try `bmesh.ops.translate(bm, vec=(0, 1, 0), verts=[v for v in ext["geom"] if isinstance(v, BMVert)])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original version of the question you had an unnecessary call to `bm.free` that you removed.  In the current version of the question, there is a use of `bpy.context...` that should be just `context...` but the main problem is that the `vec` argument of `bmesh.ops.translate` takes a tuple rather than a vector argument, as shown in [this example](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html).  Here is a version of your script that works in 2.93.6:

```
import bpy, bmesh
from bmesh.types import BMVert

class MESH_OT_Generate_Arms(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Generate Arms"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.generate_arms"
    bl_label = "Generate Arms"

    def execute(self, context):
        
        ### START ###

        #create cube
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=0.1)
        
        # turn on edit mode
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        
        # get the mesh data of the active object
        ao_d = context.active_object.data
        
        # get bmesh from ao_d
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(ao_d)

        bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
        # extrude
        ext = bmesh.ops.extrude_face_region(bm, geom=[bm.faces[1]])
        
        # translate
        bmesh.ops.translate(bm, vec=(0, 1, 0), verts=[v for v in ext["geom"] if isinstance(v, BMVert)])
        
        bm.normal_update()
        
        # update the viewport so we can see what we are doing
        bmesh.update_edit_mesh(ao_d, True, True)
        
        # return to object mode
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

        ### END ###
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
      
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MESH_OT_Generate_Arms)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MESH_OT_Generate_Arms)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

For completeness, here's a blend file with the version that works for me.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it still crashes when I run it in the python terminal with `bpy.ops.mesh.generate_arms()` but just like before I can run it in the terminal just by cutting and pasting the pertinent lines of code. But I do appreciate the help and I'm sure those are bugs that you squashed. I added another screenshot to the OP.

Comment: It should not give you error messages if you do that.  Try going to the 3d viewport, typing F3, and searching for "generate" and executing it that way.  That should work.

Comment: Going to a 3d viewport, then F3, and searching then clicking "Generate Arms" causes blender to immediately crash.

Comment: maybe a 2.93.5 bug?  I've upgraded to 2.93.6

Comment: I upgraded to 2.93.6 same result, maybe it is a bug

Comment: I'm not sure what the change was, but when I downloaded your blend and tried it, everything worked. So then I used a difference tool (Meld) to compare your file with mine, and made the changes to my file (nothing really important just some formatting and comments. But for some reason after making yours match mine, mine also works. Thanks a lot for all the help. Very puzzling, but it works. :)

Comment: I wish I had it in version control so I could go back and see exactly what the changes were.